# Symfony2 firewalls allow IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED

Tags: symfony

My website must be like that:

The user can't access to any page if he isn't logged normaly or with remembered except for the login and registering page. But it's not working for remembered users.

Here my firewalls:

```
firewalls:
    login:
        pattern:   ^/login/
        anonymous: true # On autorise alors les anonymes sur ce pare-feu
    register:
        pattern:   ^/register/
        anonymous: true # On autorise alors les anonymes sur ce pare-feu
    main_login:
        pattern:   ^/home$
        anonymous: true # On autorise alors les anonymes sur ce pare-feu
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            login_path: user_security_login
            check_path: user_security_check
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
        logout:       true
        remember_me:
            key:   %secret%
        anonymous:    false
```

The problem is "anonymous: false" because AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED are anonymous.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you dont need so many firewalls, you just need some access_control for your main firewall. Here an example, should do what you like.

```
   access_control:
       - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
       - { path: ^/login_check$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY } 
       - { path: ^/register$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY } 
       - { path: ^/home$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY } 
       - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: Seems I have added a $ to much, use just ^/register . The $ means the url ends there